# Rendering PDF with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm new in javascript. I'm Trying to render a pdf with pdf.js. and I get this error:
`Parsing Error: Unexpected token const`

from this code:
`const url = '../docs/pdf.pdf';`

My Code

```js
const url = '../docs/pdf.pdf';

let pdfDoc = null,
  pageNum = 1,
  pageIsRendering = false,
  pageNumIsPending = null;

const scale = 1.5,
  canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const renderPage = num => {
  pageIsRendering = true;


  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
   
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderCtx = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport
    };

    page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
      pageIsRendering = false;

      if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
        pageNumIsPending = null;
      }
    });

   
    document.querySelector('#page-num').textContent = num;
  });
};


const queueRenderPage = num => {
  if (pageIsRendering) {
    pageNumIsPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
};


const showPrevPage = () => {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};


const showNextPage = () => {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};

pdfjsLib
  .getDocument(url)
  .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

    document.querySelector('#page-count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    renderPage(pageNum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
   
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'error';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
    document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(div, canvas);
   
    document.querySelector('.top-bar').style.display = 'none';
  });


document.querySelector('#prev-page').addEventListener('click', showPrevPage);
document.querySelector('#next-page').addEventListener('click', showNextPage);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>PDF Viewer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <button class="btn" id="prev-page">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Prev Page
      </button>
      <button class="btn" id="next-page">
        Next Page <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
      <span class="page-info">
        Page <span id="page-num"></span> of <span id="page-count"></span>
      </span>
    </div>

    <canvas id="pdf-render"></canvas>

    <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hallo. Where are you trying to let this run? what charset is your file using? Does it habe a BOM?

Comment: Hi. I run the code in Brackets. The charset is UTF-8, and it has BOM.

Comment: Try to rename const to war and see if the same line fails. If so try to remove the BOM.

Comment: Now i'm getting this error: Unexpected identifier. Without the BOM is the same.

Comment: The your enviorment does not support the let/const keywords. Use var instead or upgrade your enviorment?

Comment: When I changed to var, the error is: Unexpected token let. How can I upgrade the environment?

Comment: Like i said. dont ahve the let AND const keywords. replace all of the acordingly. I don't know how to do that :/